# How to achieve similar effects to systemNavigationAction on iOS17

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension, ios17

I want to automatically return to the application where the keyboard is located after opening the host application from the keyboard extension. This can be achieved under iOS17 using systemNavigationAction.

I'm trying This :

```
@import UIKit;
@import ObjectiveC.runtime;

@interface UISystemNavigationAction : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, readonly, nonnull) NSArray<NSNumber*>* destinations;
-(BOOL)sendResponseForDestination:(NSUInteger)destination;
@end

inline BOOL jumpBackToPreviousApp() {
    Ivar sysNavIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(UIApplication.class,     "_systemNavigationAction");
    UIApplication* app = UIApplication.sharedApplication;
    UISystemNavigationAction* action = object_getIvar(app, sysNavIvar);
    if (!action) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSUInteger destination = action.destinations.firstObject.unsignedIntegerValue;
    return [action sendResponseForDestination:destination];
}
```

but object_getIvar return nil;

Comment: The only way that I've found works in iOS 17 is to use LSApplicationWorkspace, but it's unfortunately rejected by Apple.